# Improve cascading parameter performance report builder 3.0 SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, report, reporting, builder

I currently have an issue about the performance of the filters in report builder 3.0. I have some cascading parameters such as country, city, address. Address is dependent on city, and city is dependent on country. So that when I chose a value of filter country, the filter city and address will be reloaded and filtered by that selected country. The problem is that the reload processing is too slow. (I have run that sql query manually in oracle and I saw that it's more faster than running by report builder).

Could you please suggest some solution or share me some document to improve that performance?
I'm very grateful for your helps. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you choose a country, are both the city and address filter queries running? Maybe if you set the Address filter query to not run unless a city is returned, that could speed things up a bit...

Comment: Thanks molleyc. Could you please show me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are passing the City parameter to the query that is pulling Addresses?  You could surround your Addresses SELECT statement with a condition that will only pass and run the select statement if City IS NOT NULL (I'm not that familiar with Oracle queries, so I'm not sure how it would translate to Oracle...), something like:

```
IF @City IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT (Addresses select statement here)
END
```